# C++: int i; sizeof(++i); ... i does not increase in value?

Tags: c++, increment

I did this:

```
int i=1;
sizeof(++i);
cout<<i;
```

…and the output is 1. Why did the integer not increment in its value?

I know it might be a stupid question, but I didn't know where else to ask/search for the answer.

Comment: The short answer is "because sizeof is a compile-time operator. The result is based only on the *type* of the argument, and the argument itself is *not* evaluated."

Answer (score 4):

`sizeof` is determined by the compiler at compile time, and only the type of the argument matters.  That's why you can have, e.g.

```
int *list = malloc(10*sizeof(*list));
```

Even though `list` is uninitialized at the `sizeof`.